# Create New point

Tags: c#, sharpmap

creating new point with different coordinates not changing the position. 
**First point**
The bellow code  create a point on the map

```
VectorLayer pushPinLayer = new VectorLayer("PushPins");
            position1 = new Coordinate(10, 10);
            geos.Add(gf.CreatePoint(position1));
```

**Second point**
But this case also the the point created on the same point

```
position2 = new Coordinate(20, 20);
        geos.Add(gf.CreatePoint(position2));
```

Could you please tell me why both points are in the same place.And could you please tell me how  can i make a point from latitude and longitude.

I am using Google Mercator"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason why they appear in the same place is that you are looking at two points of ~14 metres differences, at a scale where they aren't distinct.

The coordinate lengths are in the spatial reference system (e.g. in Google Mercator based on your question) you are using - you need to do a transformation to convert between spatial reference systems.

If this is not a familiar concept, please use a search engine or look for other questions on this site that relate to spatial referencing. Once you understand the concept, the API will make sense. Until then, you are going to get really strange results, and creating hard-to-fix bugs for the future.

For a slightly out-of-date explanation, see https://sharpmap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Apply%20on%20the%20fly%20transformation%20to%20a%20layer
however the concepts are not SharpMap specific.